# Linking main.py with .kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to get a label which has text of string stored in `w` variable in my `main.py` file and label is in `.kv file` let me show you both files.

Here's main.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class ExampleApp(App):  
    def hell(self):
        w="hello world"
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv("exapmleapp.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

And here is my `.kv` file.

```
Label:
    text:app.w
```

Every time when I run my main.py file, it gives me this error.

> 1:
>    2:Label:
>    3:   text:app.w  ...  AttributeError: 'ExampleApp' object has no attribute 'w'    File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1649, in
>   create_handler
>        return eval(value, idmap)    File "./exampleapp.kv", line 3, in 
>        text:app.w    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 858, in
>   **getattribute**
>        return getattr(object.**getattribute**(self, '_obj'), name)
>        File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 2011, in _apply_rule
>        value, rule, rctx['ids'])    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1654, in
>   create_handler
>        cause=tb)

How can I get the label that has text stored in w variable in my main.py file

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the .kv file can see attributes inside the function you are calling. 
As you can see in the example below, I've moved the 'w' attribute outside the function.

Edit: aah it seems you want to change the displayed label when function **hell()** is called. 
Firstly we need an easy way to refer to the label. Kivy uses the **id tag**, and the list of ids can be found in **self.ids**

Having the 'w' variable is no longer necessary, but I've left in there as it does answer the *original* question.

So, this should work in theory:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class ExampleApp(App):  
  w = "hello"
  def hell(self):
    self.ids.mylabel.text = "world"
  def build(self):
    self.load_kv("exapmleapp.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  ExampleApp().run()
```

And the .kv file:

```
Label:
  id: mylabel
  text:app.w
```

Comment: I know this...but i need to call it from that function...is there any solution ?

Comment: Do you mean you only want 'w' to be set to "hello" when you run the hell() function? If so, you can declare 'w' as w="" outside the function and only change it to w="hello" inside the hell() function. I'll modify my answer appropriately if thats what you are looking for.

Comment: Ya but after modifying w and set it w ='hello world' i need the same text on label as well

Comment: Okay, got ya. I've modified the answer accordingly :)